# Vectors and coordinate

Tags: vector-spaces

I hope my question is relevant.
In a 2d plan vectors have coordinates, and i know that the coordinate is the move from the startpoint to the endpoint, but if we say for example, u(2, 3) and v(1, 6) is the vectors start at the same point ? how can we know where the vector is in the plan ?

Comment: You can parallelly shift any vector and it remains the same.

Comment: thanks i understand better now

Comment: A vector is better thought of as a step, a displacement. It is bow clear that they may begin at the same point. The same person may execute them, or if you want to see them simultaneously in action, let two people execute them.

Comment: okay interesting, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, imagine a plane $\overrightarrow{\mathbb{R}^2}=\{\overrightarrow{(u,v)}\,;\,u,v\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where you consider the element $\overrightarrow{(u,v)}$ to be the arrow starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(u,v)$. Now imagine a second plane $\mathbb{R}^2=\{(x,y)\,;\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where you consider the element $(x,y)$ to be the point (dot) of coordinates $(x,y)$. The first space can act on the second one: define

$$(x,y)+\overrightarrow{(u,v)}=(x+u,y+v),$$

thus getting a new point from the data of a point and an arrow (the arrow "joining" the two points).

If you have two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, there will always be a unique arrow $\overrightarrow{(u,v)}$ joining them: namely, the previous formula forces it to be $\overrightarrow{(u,v)}=\overrightarrow{(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)}$. But you can get the same arrow from different couple of points: for example, $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ are joined by $\overrightarrow{(1,1)}$, but so are $(17,134)$ and $(18,135)$. So with one arrow, you can join an infinity of couple of points.